# How to refresh google sheets pivot table without deleting filters?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Apparently the filter in a pivot table in google sheets will block all updates to the pivot table when the source data (e.g. in another sheet) changes.
As described here: https://sheetsformarketers.com/how-to-refresh-a-pivot-table-in-google-sheets/

But this renders the filters completely useless, because the source data will change all the time (e.g. by adding new entries every week or changing existing entries)

Is there a way to get this to work with filters in a pivot table?

Comment: What exactly is your filter condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to me that you might be using the "wrong" filter.

here is a pic to illustrate.  maybe you are using filter by Values, and instead you need to be using filter by Condition?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 

Now I noticed that all my pivot tables had a "Filter by values" that was automatically added. And that filter was applied on the "value" column. That (for some reason) was not updated when I chaged the "value" in the source table. It simply was filtered out.

And the documentation was confusing, because the suggestion to "remove all filters and add them back" seemed to be a ridiculous proposal.